# Edit a append element in the html form

Tags: jquery, html

I have done a html form like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-IN">
<head>
    <title>jQuery Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="left-sidebar">

  <div id="input-box" class="element" >Input Box</div>
  <div id="text-area" class="element" >Text Area</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <form id="myForm">
  </form>
</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

Now I want create a input box with jQuery code. Which I have done here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  textBox = 'Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />';
  jQuery('#input-box').click(function() {
    jQuery('#myForm').append(textBox);
  });

  jQuery('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

After that I got a input box append in to the form as "Name:   ". How can I make the name field editable by jQuery, by which one edit the name as per his requirement.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the `Name:` label editable? If so, how would you expect someone to change it? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Who do you expect the user to specify the value?

Comment: which name field ? the one within input `name="name1"` or the `Name : ` part?

Comment: Umm, you keep clicking `#input-box` you'l have multiple `inputs` with same `id` and `name` as `name1`.

Comment: Its working fine.. i think http://jsfiddle.net/aGH4X/

Comment: Voting to close as this question is about as vague as it gets.

Comment: i want to do the Name lable editable. So that the text field label can edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use onChange function to dynamically edit the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line 
`textBox = 'Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />';` 
to this: 
`textBox = '<label for="name1">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />';`
 After that you can `get` and `set` the label text using this code:  `$('label[for="name1"]').html();`